# SQL Count No of Mondays tuesdays etc from year

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, datepart

I want to create a table which will show me a count of every weeks day for the current year by months as shown in the table below.

I know i need to use a with statement but have not managed to crack it just yet.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008 r2 and I am also a Junior in SQL So any help will be greatly appreciated

OUTPUT Expected:

```
Month       Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Sum
-------------------------------------------
January     4   5   5   5   4   4   4   31
February    4   4   4   4   4   4   4   28
March       4   4   4   4   5   5   5   31
April       5   5   4   4   4   4   4   30
May         4   4   5   5   5   4   4   31
June        4   4   4   4   4   5   5   30
July        5   5   5   4   4   4   4   31
August      4   4   4   5   5   5   4   31
September   5   4   4   4   4   4   5   30
October     4   5   5   5   4   4   4   31
November    4   4   4   4   5   5   4   30
December    5   5   4   4   4   4   5   31
```

Comment: Hint: you need DATEPART and multiple SUM(CASE WHEN )

Comment: Which database are you really using?

Comment: is there a chance you can explain how this query works basically i want to be also be able to use a date field from my database to find out what how many days work has been completed and then work out the difference of the current years calender against the data in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-- count weekdays in a year
declare @y int = 2013
declare @d datetime = dateadd(year, @y - 1900, 0)

;with cte
as
(
    select 1 a, 
      left(datename(weekday, @d), 3) b,
      datename(month, 0) Month,
      1 sort
    union all
    select a + 1 a, 
      left(datename(weekday, @d + a), 3) b, 
      datename(month, @d + a) Month, 
      datepart(month, @d + a) sort
    from cte where a < datepart(dayofyear, dateadd(year, 1, @d)-1)
)
select month, [Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thu],[Fri],[Sat],[Sun], 
     [Mon]+[Tue]+[Wed]+[Thu]+[Fri]+[Sat]+[Sun] [Sum] 
from cte
pivot (count(a) FOR [b] IN ([Mon],[Tue],[Wed],[Thu],[Fri],[Sat],[Sun],[Sum])) AS pvt
order by sort 
option (maxrecursion 366)
```

Comment: awesome! this also shows hot to use cte recursively and how to call the first cte with the second. blows my mind...

Comment: You are the bomb, exactly what i needed, very pleased.